# .NET events not visible/working for use with vb6(vba)?

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6

I have written an vb.net class which I want to make COM-visible for VB6.  I have an old application which was developed in VB6, and I am in the process of rewrite it entirely for .net, but in the meantime I need to get this class working and get it usable together with VB6.

All the methods exposed to COM seems to work as they should, but I can't get the event to work with VB6.  I have crawled the net for weeks now, and have found a lot of information which have helped me to the point I am now.  The problem is when I try to select the class in the dropdown list inside the VB6 IDE, the IDE creates an eventhandler directly(in my case sub tc_Pls_changeprice()). What's strange is that it's not possible for me to select or mark the actual class, and then pick the event from the event dropdown list.

If I doesn't try to select the class first, but select the event directly from the event dropdownlist, I am able to select it(but the name of it is tc_Pls_changeprice, and not Pls_changeprice as I should expect)

If I select it two or more times, the IDE generates new eventhandlers rather than jump into the already created eventhandler.

When I try to put code inside the eventhandler, my vb6 testapplication compiles and run, but the event doesn't fire.

I have attached my .net code and my vb6 testapplication code.

The .dll has been compiled with `ComVisible` activated, but not register as com-interop(since I need to register the dll on other machines).  I register the dll on the host machines with regasm /TLB /codebase option, and the TLB that is generated is located together with the DLL inside same directory as my vb6 source directory.

Duplicate eventhandlers:

[image]

This picture shows that its something wrong with the event dropdown event list, and I'm not able to first select the class from the left dropdown list:

[image]

Have anybody any ideas of what's wrong?

Here is my .net code for the class:

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Timers

<Guid("ABEF0C71-17CE-4d38-BEFD-71770E7D50B4")>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Interface Itaxcomm
    <DispId(1)> Property commport As String
    <DispId(2)> ReadOnly Property taxstatus As String
    <DispId(3)> Function open() As Integer
    <DispId(4)> Function close() As Integer

    <DispId(5)> Sub testevent()

    <DispId(6)> Sub Reset()
    <DispId(7)> Sub ChangepriceOK()
    <DispId(8)> Sub Triggerstartbutton()
    <DispId(9)> Sub TaxState()

End Interface

<Guid("A68C5882-21B2-4827-AA0F-A8D6538D1AE3")>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)>
    <ComVisible(True)>
    Public Interface ItaxcommEvents
    <DispId(10)> Sub Pls_changeprice()
    End Interface


    <ComVisible(True)>
    <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
    <ComDefaultInterface(GetType(Itaxcomm))>
    <ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(ItaxcommEvents))>
    <Guid("0F998406-B0CF-440a-8A78-262015480C90")>
    <ProgId("Taxcomm.taxcomm")>
    Public Class taxcomm
    Implements Itaxcomm
    Public Status As String
    <ComVisible(False)>
    Public Delegate Sub pls_changepricedelegate()
    Public Event Pls_changeprice As pls_changepricedelegate
    Private _comport As String
    Private _taxmode As String
    Private rxByte(4096) As Byte
    Private WithEvents statetimer As New Timer
    Private WithEvents sp As New SerialPort

        Private Property Itaxcomm_commport As String Implements Itaxcomm.commport

            Get
                Return _comport

            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _comport = value

            End Set
        End Property

        Private ReadOnly Property Itaxcomm_taxstatus As String Implements Itaxcomm.taxstatus

            Get
                Return _taxmode


            End Get


        End Property

        Private Sub sp_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles sp.DataReceived
            Dim s As String = ""
            If sp.BytesToRead < 7 Then Exit Sub

            sp.Read(rxByte, 0, 7)
            For i = 0 To 20
                s = s + (rxByte(i).ToString) & " "
            Next i

        If rxByte(0) = &H48 And rxByte(6) = &H54 And rxByte(5) = (rxByte(0) Xor rxByte(1) Xor rxByte(2) Xor rxByte(3) Xor rxByte(4)) Then
                Select Case rxByte(3)
                    Case 0
                        Select Case rxByte(4)
                            Case 0              ''Normal_mode(with tax)
                                _taxmode = 1
                            Case 1              ''!Normal_mode(Ex tax)
                                _taxmode = 0
                        End Select

                    Case 1
                        Select Case rxByte(4)
                            Case 0              ''Pls_changeprice
                                RaiseEvent Pls_changeprice()

                            Case 1
                        End Select
                    Case 253
                        Select Case rxByte(4)
                            Case 0              ''Buffer overflow
                                Status = "Tax rx:Buffer overflow"

                        End Select

                    Case 255
                        Select Case rxByte(4)
                            Case 0

                            Case 1              ''Command unknown
                                Status = "Tax rx:Command unknown"


                            Case 2             ''ERROR_CRC
                                Status = "Tax rx:ERROR or CRC error"

                        End Select
                End Select

            End If
        End Sub
        Private Sub TestEvent() Implements Itaxcomm.testevent
            RaiseEvent Pls_changeprice()

        End Sub
        Private Sub sp_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sp.Disposed

        End Sub

        Private Sub sp_ErrorReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs) Handles sp.ErrorReceived
            Status = "TAX commerror:" & e.ToString
        End Sub

        Private Sub Taxstate() Implements Itaxcomm.TaxState
            Dim txarray = New Byte() {&H16, &H6, &H63, &H1, &H72, &H54}
            sptx(txarray)
        End Sub
        Public Sub Triggerstartbutton() Implements Itaxcomm.Triggerstartbutton
            Dim txarray = New Byte() {&H16, &H6, &H63, &H4, &H77, &H54}
            sptx(txarray)
        End Sub
        Public Sub ChangepriceOK() Implements Itaxcomm.ChangepriceOK
            Dim txarray = New Byte() {&H16, &H6, &H63, &H2, &H71, &H54}
            sptx(txarray)
        End Sub

        Public Sub Reset() Implements Itaxcomm.Reset

            Dim txarray = New Byte() {&H16, &H6, &H63, &H3, &H70, &H54}
            sptx(txarray)
        End Sub

        Private Sub statetimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles statetimer.Elapsed
            If sp.IsOpen Then Taxstate()
        End Sub
        Private Sub sptx(a() As Byte)
            Do Until sp.BytesToWrite = 0

            Loop
            sp.Write(a, 0, a.Count)
        End Sub

        Public Function open() As Integer Implements Itaxcomm.open
            Try

                sp.BaudRate = 9600
                sp.DataBits = 8
                sp.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
                sp.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                sp.RtsEnable = True
                sp.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1

                sp.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One

                If _comport <> "" And Not sp.IsOpen Then
                    sp.PortName = _comport
                    sp.Open()
                    statetimer.Interval = 1000
                    statetimer.Enabled = True
                    Return 0

                Else
                    Return 1
                End If


            Catch ex As Exception
                Status = "Serialport open:" & Err.Description
                Return 1
            End Try
        End Function

        Public Function close() As Integer Implements Itaxcomm.close
            Try
                If sp.IsOpen Then sp.Close()
                statetimer.Enabled = False

                Return 0
            Catch ex As Exception
                Status = "Serialport close:" & Err.Description
                Return 1

            End Try
        End Function
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
    End Class:
```

and here is my vb6 testapplication code:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents tc As taxcomm.taxcomm

Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Error GoTo errhandler

tc.Triggerstartbutton
Exit Sub
errhandler:
Text1.Text = Err.Number & Err.Description

End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
On Error GoTo errhandler
tc.Reset
Exit Sub
errhandler:
Text1.Text = Err.Number & Err.Description

End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
tc.testevent

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo errhandler

Set tc = CreateObject("Taxcomm.taxcomm")

tc.commport = "COM5"
If tc.Open = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Active"

Else
    MsgBox "Not active"
    tc.Close

End If
Exit Sub
errhandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume Next

End Sub


Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
tc.Close

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Terminate()
tc.Close

End Sub


Private Sub tc_Pls_changeprice()
MsgBox "test"
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
On Error GoTo errhandler

Text1.Text = tc.taxstatus
Exit Sub
errhandler:
Text1.Text = Err.Number & Err.Description

tc.Close

End Sub
```

The .net class and the vb6 testapplication compiles as it should, but it seems to be something wrong with the generation of the TLB(due to something wrong in my .net code) so the event doesn't fire, and/or the exposed event are not correctly registered inside VB6 IDE.

Comment: I typically let the compiler handle the interface generation by using the [ComClassAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.comclassattribute?view=netframework-4.8).  The emitted code places `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)` on the class implemented interface where-as you are using `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)`.  Also it uses the default on the events interface which is `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)` where-as you are using `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)`.  May be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your tip,  I tried it, but with no solution to the problem. I will try to use the ComClassAttribute as well.

Comment: Declarations look good, but the DataReceived event is a significant problem.  VB6 requires you to raise the event on the same thread that created the object.  The *expected* behavior is that you still get the event, but the program will behave quite badly, most typically dying on an exception that isn't actually caused by an exception.  But realistically anything is possible.  You need to marshal to the correct thread yourself and that might not be easy to do.  For now create a Form object in Sub New, call its CreateHandle method.  Call its BeginInvoke method in DataReceived.

Comment: It is rather strange that the event appears twice in the VB6 editor.  Everything looks entirely correct however when I copy/paste the code and look at the generated type library.  Which is as far as I can take it, VB6 is no more on my machines.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the declarations are good and it should work.  Regarding the datareceived threading problem, I'm aware of it, but I haven't put to much effort in this part of code yet.  The problem with selecting the event, and that it generates multiple eventhandlers is as you say very strange.  For  your information, I also tried to open Excel VBA to see if the same happend here. It did, so I don't think my VB6 editor has problems either.   I recorded a video that shows exactly what is happening with the dropdown lists inside vb6.  [link](https://youtu.be/3kB_kEWL3LU)

Comment: For your information,when I tried out the class in excel VBA, this was carried out on an different machine than VB6 IDE is installed at..same behaviour.  The class is compiled with .net framework 3.5. I use VS2015

Comment: Surprising as it may sound, I've found that VB6 has some limitations when dealing with underscores in method and event names when doing some more advanced COM component . COM interop type stuff.  This was years ago, so I cannot recall what pain point I specifically hit.  A bit of a longshot, but just for the heck of it, try to rename you event to avoid the underscore.

Comment: OMG!:-)  Never use underscores:-) I removed the underscore from the event declaration so its name became plschangeprice and VOILA,it worked like a charm!  Thank you so much!  I have bounced my head in the wall for weeks now. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was originally in a comment, but putting this here to make clear what the answer was:

Surprising as it may sound, I've found that VB6 has some limitations when dealing with underscores in method and event names when doing some more advanced COM component / COM interop type stuff. This was years ago, so I cannot recall what pain point I specifically hit. A bit of a longshot, but just for the heck of it, try to rename you event to avoid the underscore

Comment: Good catch, I suspect that it has something to do with the [Bad interface for Implements: method has underscore in name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/bad-interface-for-implements-method-has-underscore-in-name) error, but the error checking somehow misses it on event names.